# Get %AppData% path (or other environment variable) for Git hook on Windows (10)

Tags: regex, git, githooks

Is it possible to get the %AppData% path within a git hook on my Windows 10 machine?

I am attempting to use it to call gulp.... so maybe even the environment variable %NODE_PATH% which I also have....but essentially I want to get the path of the environment variable.

I currently have:-

```
gulp="/c/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp.cmd"
echo $gulp
```

and then I can call gulp successfully..... but I'd like not to hardcode my username in the path....and rather have something like:-

```
gulp="%AppData%/gulp.cmd"
echo $gulp
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my Git Bash:

```
$ export gulp=`echo $APPDATA | sed -e 's/^C:/\/c/;s/\\\\/\//g;s/$/\\/npm\\/gulp\\.cmd/' `

$ gulp
No gulpfile found
```

The `sed` transforms the Windows path into something in Bash format, with each regular expression separated by a semicolon:

Change "C:\" to "/c":

```
s/^C:/\/c/
```

Change the remaining backslashes:

```
s/\\\\/\//g
```

Append the gulp command:

```
s/$/\\/npm\\/gulp\\.cmd/
```

The backticks evaluate the expression, and they requiring doubling up the backslashes used for escaping the regex special characters.

Comment: ...or used a different separator for sed: `s!\\\\!/!g` and `s!$!/npm/gulp.cmd!`